# How do I form a new string by selecting characters from an old one?

Tags: c++, string

I need to reformat a string which represents the date from DD/MM/YYYY to YYYY/DD/MM. I thought the best way to do this would be to : Declare 3 variables day, month and year. Then select the characters from the old string to store in the new strings and concatenate them in the end. How can I do something like this in C++?

Comment: Your sketched approach suggest that you have the date string in a `char` array. Then you can consider to move the items around with temp variables. If you work with `std::string` you can use the `substr` function of the `string` class. Try something like  `y = x.substr(7,4) + "/" + x.substr(0,2) + "/" + x.substr(3,2)` http://cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/substr/

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how robust you want the code to be. For instance if the incoming format is actually D/M/YYYY (for example 1/2/2020) do you want the code to return an error? throw an exception? Or treat 1/2/2020 as 01/02/2020? If it's the last you will need to find the '/' delimiters as part of determining the values for day month and year. This can be hand coded  in a separate subroutine (good if learning C++) or by using `std::string::find` and `std::string::substring` if not.